# losing session on refresh NodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am following a tutorial on Udemy and creating a react app using node and express. I am losing my session and being sent back to the login page on refresh. The instructors app stays in session on refresh. Could bad routing be causing this issue? I'll provide auth.js file from my routing folder. I can add more if needed.

<<< SERVER.JS file >>>

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

//  CONNECT To Database
connectDB();

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({extended: false}))

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Well, hello there!'));

app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));
app.use('/api/profile', require('./routes/api/profile'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server is listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

<<< middleware >>>

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  // Get token from header
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  // Check if not token
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'No token, authorization denied' });
  }

  // Verify token
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));

    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' });
  }
};
```

just in case my here is my auth.js file from routing folder

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const auth = require('../../middleware/auth');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('config');
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const User = require('../../models/User');

// @route    GET api/auth
// @desc     Test route
// @access   Public
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});

// @route    POST api/auth
// @desc     Authenticate user & get token
// @access   Public
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Password is required').exists()
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
      let user = await User.findOne({ email });

      if (!user) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' }] });
      }

      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

      if (!isMatch) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Invalid Credentials' }] });
      }

      const payload = {
        user: {
          id: user.id
        }
      };

      jwt.sign(
        payload,
        config.get('jwtSecret'),
        { expiresIn: 360000 },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json({ token });
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The code you show for auth, just returns a token.  That token has to be sent back with any future requests in the header `x-auth-token` for your auth to work.  That won't happen from a browser page (which it sounds like you're using since you speak of "refresh").  This particular technique needs to either put the token in a cookie (the browser will send back the cookie on each request) and check for it there to verify auth or this code is for programmatic access only, not for browser access.  I'm not sure what your assignment actually is to know what you're trying to accomplish.